# How to show popup center on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of products and when i click in each product shows a popup but this popup shows in top of the page and the opacity is not in all screen.

My popup:

```js
 $('.image-sample').click(function(data)
        {
          var image = $(this).attr('data-image');
          $.get("/sample-image/"+ image, function(data)
          {
            $(".popup").html('');
            $(".popup").append(data);
            $('.opacity').show();
            $('.popup').show();
            closeNews();
          });
        });
```

```css
.popup
    {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: none;
      z-index: 1000 !important;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .opacity
    {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
      opacity: 0.5;
      z-index: 998;
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="popup"></div>
<div class="opacity"></div>
```

It allow scroll when popup shows and shouldn't.

What i want is center the popup in screen and have the opacity in all screen.

What is my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Set a top and left for the opacity layer.  The popup should not be 100% width and height.  If you can set it to a fixed width and height (in pixels) then you can set left and top margins to 50% to center it.

Comment: Use https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/

Comment: @Roy why use a framework?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle example of your problem?

Comment: @madalin ivascu Why not?

Comment: @Roy There is no mention of a framework, and questions are closed when that's what they're asking for.  By all means suggest a relevant answer and *then* include mention of a framework, but to suggest one as a solution is most often the wrong thing to do.  See this scientific reference document for further info... https://howtodoinjava.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/use-jquery.gif

Comment: @Roy first the framework is big and to only add it for a modal is kind of overkill, and second the franework is still in alpha stage

Comment: Well guys, im trying to help, Bootstrap is clearly lightweight and you can use the V3 if want to use a non alpha stage. However, we are not helping, maybe the problem width div.opacity at 100% is that is not absolute to stage, is absolute to another div, make sure that divs are positioned absolute to the body.

Comment: @Roy - yes, so ask those questions and help the OP understand their problem, if you want to help.  Suggesting a framework is NOT the right way to go.

Comment: Understood guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Opacity animation issue: if you use display:none in css animation with opacity wouldnt work so i advice use in jquery not the $('.popup').show(); but fadeIn and fadeOut -  $('.opacity').fadeIn(300);
2. Use position: fixed; not the absolute for the popup blocks (.popup, .overflow);
3. The scrolling you can hide toggling with jquery to the body class or style which hides overflow and setting max-height:100%;